# Add layer to RasterBrick R

Tags: r, raster-conversion, rasterbrick

I have a RasterBrick and I am trying to add new layers to it, (with addLayer) but every time I try I receive the following message:

> Error in sapply(x, fromDisk) & sapply(x, inMemory) :    operations are
>   possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

The brick and the layers have the same crs, res, and extent, and I reprojected the brick to match the layers.

Is there anything else that might be keeping the two from merging?

The only thing I can think of is that the brick is stored on disk and the layer is stored on memory- but would that actually effect anything?

Comment: Hard to tell without your data or your code. If you use `readAll` on the stack to bring it into memory (use `inMemory` to check) does it work?

Comment: My code is just "x <- addLayer(y)". My data is the worldclim data and the elevation data (for the US) from getData (among others). I changed the extent, res and crs of worldclim to match the elevation data.
I read the brick into memory and that's not the problem

Comment: You're not adding anything to `y`. Are you trying to do `x = addLayer(x, y)`? See how important it is to show your code?

Comment: And now I'm embarrassed about how dumb I am. That was exactly the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Nah, its a badly named function! `addLayers` might be better, or it might not even be needed - you can do `stack(a,b,c)` and get the same effect I think...

Answer (score 3):

The `addLayer` function works by stacking all its arguments - to add a layer to an existing raster or stack make it the first argument. This is shown in the help:

```
 file <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
 s <- stack(file, file, file)
 r <- raster(file)
 s <- addLayer(s, r/2, r*2)
```

Running with only one argument produces that error:

```
> s = addLayer(s)
Error in sapply(x, fromDisk) & sapply(x, inMemory) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Its not a particularly infomative error message.

`addLayer` appears to be equivalent to `stack`:

```
> s3 = stack(s,s,s)
> as3 = addLayer(s,s,s)
```

except in the case of adding nothing! `stack(s) === s` in this case!